# How do I access the Straits of Devastation?

Tags: guild-wars-2

According to the [official Guild Wars 2](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Straits_of_Devastation) wiki it's possible to reach the Straits of Devastation from Lornar's Pass, along with quite a few other locations. I've tried finding the location in Lornar's Pass, which I have fully explored, but I've met with little success.

How do I access the Straits of Devastation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sparkfly Fen southeast corner and Mount Maelstrom southwest corner
\

Answer (score 4):

Lornar's Pass is home to the Durmand Priory's base of operations.

They maintain an asura gate between their HQ and Fort Trinity.

Comment: It would appear this entrance can only be accessed if you've joined the Durmand Priory order.

Comment: Does this mean the portal in the Whispers camp goes to Fort Trinity also?

Comment: @DavidYell Yes it does.

Comment: You should be able to access each order portals as soon as you have accomplished the battle of fort trinity (if I remember correctly).